# Как отследить изменение input[text] в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть `input[text]` и две кнопки "+" и "-", которые изменяют значение в `input` на +1 или -1. Требуется перехватить событие, когда значение будет больше определенного, например больше 10 и выполнить функцию.

Как это можно сделать средствами JS / jQuery?

Comment: Работает!!)) Спасибо большое, даже не представляете как выручили!)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/113173)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаем функцию `checkCount`, которая при обращении в реальном времени проверяет значение инпута и что-то внутри делает.
При плюсе и минусе ссылаемся на нее.

P.S. В коде также предусмотрен вариант ввода вручную - тогда тоже идет ссылка на функцию `checkCount`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#plus', function(){
  var count = Number($('#count').val());
  $('#count').val(count+1);
  checkCount();
});

$(document).on('click', '#minus', function(){
  var count = Number($('#count').val());
  $('#count').val(count-1);
  checkCount();
});

$(document).on('input', '#count', checkCount);

function checkCount() {
  var count = Number($('#count').val());
  if(count > 10) {
    alert('Больше десяти');
  }
  else if(count < 0) {
    alert('Меньше нуля');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="minus">-</button> <input type="text" id="count" /> <button id="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".target").on("input",function() {
  console.log($(".target").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="target" type="text" placeholder="введите что-нибудь">
```